# Validation of Conditional String Android

Tags: java, android

I have been trying to validate a sample string which I read from a file. I want to check if the condition in the given string evaluates to true or false.

```
String Test = "( ((10>20) & (10>5)) & (7>9) ) | (123>45)";
```

How can I do that using Java. I have been trying to split the brackets and operators. Is there any easy way to solve this kind of textual expressions?

I have tried JSR.JAR but I'm getting

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lsun/misc/Service;                                                                            at javax.script.ScriptEngineManager.initEngines(ScriptEngineManager.java:108)at javax.script.ScriptEngineManager.access$000(ScriptEngineManager.java:55)at javax.script.ScriptEngineManager$1.run(ScriptEngineManager.java:98)at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:45)at javax.script.ScriptEngineManager.init(ScriptEngineManager.java:96)at javax.script.ScriptEngineManager.(ScriptEngineManager.java:69)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19383953/is-it-possible-to-evaluate-a-boolean-expression-for-string-comparions

Comment: I have tried using ScriptEngine But Im getting the above exception.

Comment: Ah, I see, sorry. Maybe you can use a third party library on android like this: https://github.com/ericwlange/AndroidJSCore or this built on top of googles V8 engine: http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/getting-started-with-j2v8/

Answer (score 0):

It seems that android does not provide the java scripting engine.

Possibly you could use a third party library instead:

- [AndroidJSCore](https://github.com/ericwlange/AndroidJSCore)
- [J2V8](https://github.com/eclipsesource/j2v8) (java wrapper built on top of googles V8 engine)